# Media Queries not Working when using GoDaddy Redirect

Tags: html, css

I have a website: http://the.bailbond.agency

In GoDaddy, I have a few URL redirects set up. An example of this is http://pontiac.bailbond.agency

My media queries I have set up don't work when visiting the second link. I've done some research, and from what I can tell, GoDaddy's URL redirect puts the page you're loading into an i frame, which is causing the media queries to fail. Is this the case, and if so, what can I do to fix it?

Edit: I tried using Firefox, and I have no problem, so I think it's a Chrome issue, as I was using Chrome on my PC and my phone originally.

Comment: Both of those addresses behave the same for me with respect to responsive behavior and the mobile menu. What's the problem?

Comment: Same here on the latest update of Firefox

Comment: I've tested in Chrome on my pc (Inspecting and turning on mobile view) and on my Android, and in both cases, the page won't load correctly. Could it be a Chrome-related issue?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715095/media-queries-within-an-iframe-or-scorm-without-frames

Comment: I see differences in the mobile view of the dev tools of Firefox. Media queries don't work properly in the pontiac.bailbond.agency website, even in Firefox.